# Cannot get links/ routes to work in my React App

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to teach myself React. I building a basic 3 page website to do so, and on the local host, everything seems fine. When I deploy to Netlify or anywhere else, the 2 pages other than the home to do not work.

I am not sure if this is a route issue or if the other pages are even getting build

I have tried changing the different types of routes.

Again this is me trying to learn, and everything I read, it appears im doing it right.

This is in a custom Nav bar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav, Item, Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class CustomNavbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar collapseOnSelect bg="dark" variant ="dark" >
                <Container>
             <Navbar.Brand>Deadman Jerky</Navbar.Brand>  
             <Navbar.Toggle /> 
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav" className="justify-content-end" mr-5>
                <Nav className="justify-content-end" mr-5>
                <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link eventKey={1} componentClass={Link} href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Item >
                <Nav.Link eventKey={2} componentClass={Link} href="order">Order</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link eventKey={3} componentClass={Link} href="about">About</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the links in this navbar working..

Comment: May be minor, but have you tried putting a `/` in front of `order` and `about`? `href="/about"`

Comment: Ya, this is my code after several attempts.. I just ended up here

Comment: https://medium.com/@sschannak/netlify-and-react-router-1537aebe6256

Comment: this did not work. The navigation works. When i click the link or button i go to the page, it just says the page is not there. "Page not Found"